# Bold line headings RegEx help needed

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying add a bold/strong tag the line headings of the follow string/text block:

> Length Determination: the dimensions
>   above show what center-to-center
>   length can be achieved by the
>   connecting linkage length shown for
>   male spherical rod ends.
>
> Material: aluminum.
>
> Specials: specials are available at
>   any volume.
>
> Standards: MCP offers

But I can't get the regex to include multiple words.  Here's my result:

> Length **Determination**: the dimensions
>   above show what center-to-center
>   length can be achieved by the
>   connecting linkage length shown for
>   male spherical rod ends.
>
> **Material**: aluminum.
>
> **Specials**: specials are available at
>   any volume.
>
> **Standards**: MCP offers

Notice the word "Length" in "Length Determination" isn't bold/strong.  That needs to be included.  Can someone give me a quick hand?

My code:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/([^\s]+:)/i", 'makeStrong', $str);

function makeStrong($matches) {
    return "<strong>" . $matches[0] . "</strong>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/([ \w]+:)/", 'makeStrong', $str);
```

If the pattern starts with `^`, it will only match something found in the beginning of the whole string (to me your question sounded like you wanted to process a multi-line string in one pass).

If `\s` is used together with the \w, it will match line breaks too and include them within the `<strong />`, as you probably noticed.

Comment: BINGO!  You nailed it and super small.  Well played.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?
$str = "
Length Determination: the dimensions above show what center-to-center length can be achieved by the connecting linkage length shown for male spherical rod ends.
Material: aluminum.
Specials: specials are available at any volume.
Standards: MCP offers
";

$str = preg_replace_callback("/^([\w ]+:)/mi", 'makeStrong', $str);

function makeStrong($matches) {
    return "<strong>" . $matches[0] . "</strong>"; 
}

print $str;
?>
```

Your method is failing because `[^\s]` matches "not whitespace" - meaning it won't match the spaces between words.

**EDIT** Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your `[^\s]` character class is matching anything that's *not* whitespace - which obviously means that it won't match across words that have whitespace between them. Try this instead:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/^([\w\s]+?:)/i", 'makeStrong', $str);
```

Comment: This does work in combo with my original:

preg_replace_callback("/^([\w\s]+?:)|([^\s]+:)/i", 'makeStrong', $str);